# Drupal path pattern token if/then

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I would like to do something like

```
if [node:subtitle] is available make the path pattern 
[node:title]-[node:subtitle]
else 
[node:title]
```

What is the best way to do something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it with the pathauto module I'm afraid, it simply doesn't have this functionality. You'd have to implement [`hook_node_presave()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7) and change the path manually for each node you want to do this for.